# Add Action wp_update_post not Updating WYSWIAG editor

Tags: actions

When we use the wp_update_post function, and do a pre_post_update action, it gets updated in the database, but the WYSWIAG editor shows the revision just made, not the processed one.

For example post_content = `"test 1 test2"`

Save Post Draft post_content as seen in wp-admin WYSWIAG/text = `"test 1 test2"`

Save Post Draft post_content as seen in database = `"test <span style='color : #0e9a46'>one</span> test2"`

Then if you refresh the page, WYSWIAG editor shows = `"test <span style='color : #0e9a46'>one</span> test2"` (with the HTML rendered)

Code is as follows:

```
function regexcheck($post_id){
    $post_type = get_post_type();

if ( $post_type == 'story'  ) {

    remove_action('pre_post_update', 'regexcheck');
    require_once('regex.php');

    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $response_array = regex($content);
    $update_post = $response_array['finalString'];

    $my_post = array('ID'=>$post_id, 'post_content'=> $update_post);
    wp_update_post($my_post);

    return $response_array;
    add_action('pre_post_update', 'regexcheck');

}
}
add_action('pre_post_update', 'regexcheck');
```

I tried moving the action to init but that does not solve it. Also tried putting in a sleep, but it did not work. Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why this fixed it, but it did:

```
function modify_post_content( $content ) {

    $screen =  get_current_screen();
    $post_type = $screen->post_type;
        if ($post_type == 'story'){
        require_once('regex.php');
        $response_array = regex($content);
        $content = $response_array['finalString'];
        }
        return $content;    
    }


add_filter('content_save_pre', 'modify_post_content', 10, 1);
```